# How override grails configuration from command line

Tags: grails, command-line

I am trying to override `dataSource.url` value running grails from the command line, example

```
grails <set property> dbm-status
```

My first try was using `-D` command line parameter as

```
grails -DdataSource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx;databaseName=db_name
```

I have tried to add an additional config file to `grails.config.locations` that get values from `System.getProperty` but does not seems to work.

Exist a built in way to override config values from the command line, otherwise how I can inject parameter from the command line to the grails configuration ?

EDIT: I don't want to use another environment/datasource to avoid datasource configuration duplication and the need to configure things for this new environment.

Comment: You might have to add that as a separate datasource as [shown in the docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/ref/Maintenance%20Scripts/dbm-status.html).

Comment: I am trying to launch the project using product datasource replacing only the db name. I need to run multiple time the migration scripts and do not want to duplicate the production datasource. Moreover I have url of my datasource externalized in a property files, we have 3 production environment (prod1, prod2, qa).

Answer (score 2):

By including the following `if` in  `DataSource.groovy` I'm able to override url,password and username property if url is provided. (Valid for Grails 2.x)

```
....
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db"
        username = "user"
        password = "pass"
        if (System.properties['dataSourceUrl']) {
            println 'Taking dataSource url, password, username from command line overrides'
            url = System.properties['dataSourceUrl']
            password = System.properties['dataSourcePassword']
            username = System.properties['dataSourceUsername']
        }
    }
}
...
```

Now when I run the command, the overrides get applied:

```
grails dev -DdataSourceUrl=newUrl -DdataSourcePassword=newPass -DdataSourceUsername=newUser run-app
```

Unfortunately if you want to be able to override on every environment you have to duplicate this code for every env block. If you pull it up to root it won't work since config merging kicks in and the last run will actually apply what's in the env {} block and not what's in the System properties.

Looking at it again something like that looks even better:

```
...
   url = System.properties['dataSourceUrl'] ?: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db'
   //and for every property...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx;databaseName=db_name grials run-app
```

For any variable you want to set, you can set it in the environment. Change to upper case and replace dots with underscores. This is a feature of spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

My case:
Grails 4.0.3, uses application.yml for configuration.

Command to run:

```
grails -DdataSourceUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx;databaseName=db_name"
```

Updated build.gradle (`bootRun` task and added this line):

```
// value for this property is being set in task: setDataSourceEnv
systemProperty 'dataSourceUrl', System.getProperty('dataSourceUrl')
```

The resulting task code would look like this:

```
bootRun {
    ignoreExitValue true
    jvmArgs(
            '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always',
            '-noverify',
            '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
            '-Xmx2048m')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
    // value for this property is being set in task: setDataSourceEnv
    systemProperty 'dataSourceUrl', System.getProperty('dataSourceUrl')
}
```

Updated `grails-app/conf/application.yml` to use the variable `dataSourceUrl` (it can also have dots if you prefer):

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: "${dataSourceUrl}"
```

I got the idea of using build.gradle looking at the Question itself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51681658)

Hope it helps.
Happy coding!!!