# Can't pass system property on command line using Grails 3.2.9

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-3.0

I am trying to pass a system property to Grails using the`-Dproperty=value` syntax, but it doesn't appear to be working. Here's my setup:

**build.gradle:**

```
bootRun {

     addResources = true
     systemProperties = System.properties 
 }
```

**application.yml:**

```
server:
  port: '${server_port}'
```

**Command line:**

```
grails -Dserver_port=8180 run-app
```

When I try to run the app, I get this:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "${server_port}"
```

The documentation [here](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.9/guide/conf.html#ymlOptions) suggests that this approach should work, but clearly the ${server_port} expression isn't being substituted with the value passed with the -D option.

Can anybody shed any light on what is causing this behavior?

Also, before anybody asks.. yes I know about the --port command line switch.  The point of this isn't to pass the server port specifically, although I would prefer to keep this consistent with other scripts.  But beyond that, I plan to use -Doption=value to pass other settings at run-time as well, so I really need this to work.

Comment: For Grails 4.0.3, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76020575/1403118) is the related solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be in the application.yml file.  This bit:

```
server:
   port: ${server.port}
```

actually needs to be nested under the grails element, like this:

```
grails:
  server:
    port: ${server.port}
```

When doing that it works fine.  And note that you don't actually need to do this at all, since just setting `-Dserver.port=WHATEVER` works by itself if you have the bootRun setting for passing through the system properties. Or you can use `--port`.  My interest in this was really all about making sure system properties got passed through in general, since I need to set some other properties for my application. I was just using this as an experiment.